# How to get desired dataframe as output from groupby and value counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to query a dataframe and store the results into another dataframe.

The dataframe sample I have is:

```
 train       |start     |end      |passenger_type
 rajdhani    |howrah    |allahabad|normal
 hwh indb spl|howrah    |allahabad|tatkal
 hwh indb spl|allahabad |howrah   |normal
```

I have split the dataframe into two - one for passenger_type normal and one for tatkal. Then for each dataframe corresponding to passenger_type I want the result dataframe to be like:

```
 station1  |  station2      |  frequency | freq by rajdhani| freq by hwh indb
 howrah    |  allahabad     |  2         | 1               | 1
 allahabad |  howrah        |  1         | 0               | 0
```

I am using groupby with value_counts and sorting the results, but the result is not what I want.

I am getting something like this:

```
                end
  start| end | frequency
```

The code I am using is :

```
pd.DataFrame(train.groupby('start').end.value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False))
```

Can someone please help me with the code to obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate `value_counts` on start, end and train, and then `unstack` train:

```
z = (df[['start', 'end', 'train']]
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .add_prefix('freq by '))

z['frequency'] = z.sum(1)

df_out = z.sort_values('frequency', ascending=False).reset_index()
df_out
```

Output:

```
train      start        end  freq by hwh indb spl  freq by rajdhani  frequency
0         howrah  allahabad                     1                 1          2
1      allahabad     howrah                     1                 0          1
```

---

And for example, getting start, end and frequency:

```
df_out[['start', 'end', 'frequency']]
```

Output:

```
train      start        end  frequency
0         howrah  allahabad          2
1      allahabad     howrah          1
```

Comment: Pro tip: unstack takes a `fillvalue` kwarg `.unstack(fill_value=0)` not only does this allow you to skip the `fillna` step in the chain it also keeps the type from converting to float because of `NaN` (+1 either way)

Comment: @HenryEcker That's awesome! Updated

Comment: Interesting solution. It worked. But the column names start and end are not accessible:

Comment: @KC They're just part of the index. You can reset index with `z.sort_values('frequency', ascending=False).reset_index()`, making them into columns

Comment: Uh oh! it seems to return: Index(['freq by hwh indb spl',  'freq by rajdhani', ' frequency'],dtype='object', name='train')

Comment: I really wanted to access start and end columns :( Will it not be possible :(

Comment: @KC Don't worry, we'll figure it out :) I've updated the code to save the result to `df_out`, can you check with this one?

Comment: Yippee! Thank you @perl Now I get the desired dataframe with columns just as I wanted. Thank you so much